# Need to append textbox text to the html using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css, ajax, json

I need to append user input text from the textboxes using jquery.If user types something in the Action textbox and then chooses a date from the date textbox then the values must be appended below Lunch and 12pm. Here is the example link : http://trialwebs.byethost8.com/ .
The values Wake and Lunch are appearing from the JSON file. Here is the json code :

```
{
"action": [
    {"name":"WakeUp","date":"8:00am"},
    {"name":"Lunch","date":"12:00pm"}
]}
```

I have used the following code (JS & HTML):

```js
$.getJSON("jsondata.json", function(data) {
        $.each(data.action, function(index, elem) {
            //Append option to name
            $("#name").append($("<li />", {
                text: elem.name
            }));

            //Append age
            $("#date").append($("<li />", {
                text: elem.date
            }));
        });
    });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script/myscript.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#btn2").click(function(){
            $("ol").append("<li>Appended item</li>");
        });
    });
     $(function() {
        $("#datepicker").datepicker();
      });
    </script>
    <style>
    #name{
    display:inline-block;
    }
    #date{
    display:inline-block;
    }
    li{
    list-style:none;
    }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    Action:<input type="text" name="firstname">
    Date:<input type="text" id="datepicker">
    <button id="btn2">Append list items</button>
    <br>
    <ol id="name">
    </ol>
    <ol id="date">
    </ol>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Are you running a web-server with PHP?

Comment: yes,json data will appear only on a server.

Comment: I need to add those values from the textboxes and then the textboxes must get cleared, so that I can again add the values from the textboxes by iterating it.

Comment: Here's the link for the uploaded data : 
http://trialwebs.byethost8.com/
Please help !